# Anonymous access to azure table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Please can someone give me guidance on how to set up anonymous read-only access to one specific table in Azure. I have a table that I want Power BI students to connect to without specifically adding them as users.

Comment: Welcome back! Just create one user with RO access called AnonymousStudent and limit its access to the bare minimum - ie can't even change password. or even better Shared Access Signatures for Azure Sql Server: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/simplifying-creation-of-sql-credentials-with-shared-access/ba-p/305226

Comment: I have tested both answers and they both do what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by moving SQL table to the **Blob storage**.

Please refer the below link to do that.
[Move Data from SQL Server to Azure Blob Storage with Incremental Changes – Part 1 - SQLRx by  **Ginger Daniel**](https://www.sqlrx.com/move-data-from-sql-server-to-azure-blob-storage-with-incremental-changes-part-1/#:%7E:text=Since%20we%20will%20be%20moving%20data%20from%20an,to%20create%20a%20dataset%20for%20your%20source%20data)

Then, you can set up anonymous read-only access for your table in the Blob storage.

Please follow this [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#about-anonymous-public-read-access) which explains how to configure the anonymous read-only access to the Blob data.

Comment: I have tested both answers and they both do what I need. Thank you so much.